# Idiomatic way to move std::atomic_flag (or: how are promises moved)

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I have a RAII wrapper class around an infinitely looping std::thread. The wrapper holds a `std::atomic_flag`/`std::atomic<bool>` that is shared with the thread to shut it down eventually (wrapper writes; thread reads). Everything was good until I needed to move the Wrapper class around as atomics don't have a move constructors.

**How can I move both my control flag and thread around in a thread safe manner**

My idea is to wrap the `atomic_flag` in a `shared_ptr` and give a copy to the thread. As long as I don't write to the shared_ptr (but only to the underlying atomic_flag) I am quite confident it is going to be thread safe.

However, that does not feel very idiomatic and I imagine that there is a more idiomatic way to solve this problem. It seems to me like `std::promise` must have solved a similar problem. I was trying to look into the src of libc++ but could not easily identify the code.

A sample implementation of the code looks similar to this (*updated with Nathan's input*)

```
void run(std::atomic_bool *active) {
  while (active->load()) {
     // ...
  }
}

class RaiiThread {
public:
  RaiiThread() : t_(&run, active_.get()) {}
  RaiiThread(RaiiThread &&) = default;
  ~RaiiThread() {
    if (t_.joinable()) {
      active_->store(false);
      t_.join();
    }
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<std::atomic_bool> active_{
      std::make_unique<std::atomic_bool>(true)};
  std::thread t_;
};

int main() {
  RaiiThread t1;
  auto t2 = std::move(t1);
}
```

Comment: I would use a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a `std::shared_ptr` as you don't need the extra expense shared ownership requires.

Comment: @NathanOliver but then I cannot copy the pointer to the thread to have its independent copy. And if I pass sth like a `reference_wrapper` then I assume I will have a dangling reference as soon as the Wrapper (together with the `unique_ptr`) is moved.

Comment: Sure you can.  Make the function `void run(std::atomic_bool& active)` and then `t_(&run, active_)` becomes `t_(&run, std::ref(*active_))`.

Comment: @NathanOliver good point, thanks!